# How to remove an entry from ld.so.cache?

Tags: shell

I have just added one entry use `ldconfig DIR` and it worked. But now the DIR is not needed and I want to delete it but I don't know how to do it. I have read the manual of `ldconfig` and also googled.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `man` page

> ldconfig  creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
>   shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
>   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
>   (/lib and /usr/lib).

This seems to imply that you can remove an entry by editing `/etc/ld.so.conf` manually to delete that line. Or if it was cached inside `/lib` and `/usr/lib`, you should be able to delete the links inside those trusted directories.